# Schematic failure in I2C connection

Tags: schematics, esp8266

[image: Schematic of the ESP module and MPU6050]

Hi, I've built the schematic shown in the picture. It is an ESP-12 module that should communicate via I2C to the MPU6050. However, the communication seems to be disturbed. The clock and data line produce a flat 3.3V (Vcc) output after measuring, instead of a block wave shape signal. Both modules have a working supply and it is excluded that one of these components is broken. Why do I not observe an I2C signal as output?

Comment: The resistor in AD0 could takes you into a floating value. Bridge it, because you could try to write in a different address.

Comment: run I2C scanner sketch

Comment: SCL and SDA are correctly pulled up, so, there is no error there.
The capacitor between VDD and GND is polarised? In your schematics, the positive terminal is into the gnd value.

Comment: @Juraj I'll try that.

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos the capacitor is unpolarised. The plus sign you see comes from EAGLE but is just for dragging the component. Sorry for the inconvenience. I'll try to bridge the resistor. But does that cause the flat I2C signal at the CLK port?

Comment: and to be sure of used pis use Wire.begin(4, 5);

Comment: @Juraj yes, sure of that

Comment: pins used by the library

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the I2C pins of the ESP8266 had been swapped. This was not done by me, but by the documentation that was followed. Please be careful if you use the ESP8266. Test the pins if you can.

Comment: the pis can't be swapped. I2C (Wire) is bit-banged on esp8266. it can work on any pair of pins. default pins depend on esp8266 board selected in IDE. for generic esp8266 default is 4 SDA and 5 SCL